# layoutSubviews called twice when rotating

Tags: ios, rotation, viewcontroller, layoutsubviews

When my main view rotates I want to re-arrange the sub views, so in my ViewController, I override

```
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

and set the frames of the subViews in there. This is all well and good, but in the subViews I have also overridden

```
 layoutSubviews
```

so they layout themselves correctly. But the problem is this now gets called twice - presumably once when I set the Frame in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation and once because of the rotation. (If I don't set the Frame it gets called once.)

Surely it's the responsibility of the ViewController to layout the frames so this seems like a design flaw - what's the solution so layoutSubviews is only called once?

Comment: You can save the last orientation in a private variable and execute the layoutSubviews code only if lastOrientation != currentOrientation and just after executing layoutSubviews code , set lastOrientation = currentOrientation, this way it will only get called once in a single orientation

Comment: Yea, I did think of that but seems a bit cludgy. And what if I do want to change the frame at some other time than in rotate - then layoutSubviews would not do anything! There MUST be a better way - how is this supposed to be done cleanly?

Comment: is there a problem with `-layoutSubviews` being called twice?

Comment: Well, it's not the end of the world, but it's inefficient and I'd be surprised if that was the intended design, so makes me think I'm missing something

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same question. I found [this page](http://blog.logichigh.com/2011/03/16/when-does-layoutsubviews-get-called/) to be helpful for me. Is this useful for you?

EDIT:
Here is the summary of the page (copied):

> - init does not cause layoutSubviews to be called (duh)
> - addSubview causes layoutSubviews to be called on the view being added, the view it’s being added to (target view), and all the subviews of the target view
> - setFrame intelligently calls layoutSubviews on the view having it’s frame set only if the size parameter of the frame is different
> - scrolling a UIScrollView causes layoutSubviews to be called on the scrollView, and it’s superview
> - **rotating a device only calls layoutSubview on the parent view (the responding viewControllers primary view)**
> - removeFromSuperview – layoutSubviews is called on superview only (not show in table)

Comment: Hi Armin, welcome to SO. We discourage link-only answers, can you summarize the contents of that link?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for telling me about that :) I posted the summary and marked what I find to be helpful in bold.